# How to calculate day wise available time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I've a table named `userActivity` where each active period is recorded.

Here's the table structure:

Table: **`userActivity`**

```
ID       user_id      start_time   end_time
```

When a user comes into online the `start time` is recorded and whenever the online status is changed the `end time` is recorded in the corresponding row.

Now I've to generate a report where a day wise available time of the users will be shown.

**Sample Input:**

```
ID     user_id         start_time                end_time 

'1'     '1'       '2016-02-28 10:00:00'    '2016-02-28 19:00:00'   
'2'     '1'       '2016-02-28 22:00:00'    '2016-02-29 10:00:00'
'3'     '1'       '2016-03-02 10:00:00'    '2016-03-02 19:00:00'
'4'     '1'       '2016-03-02 22:00:00'    '2016-03-06 19:00:00'
```

**Expected output:**

```
Date           AvailableTime(Hours)
2016-02-28         11 
2016-02-29         10
2016-03-02         11
2016-03-03         24
2016-03-04         24
2016-03-05         24
2016-03-06         19
```

**So far what I've tried:**

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time) availableTime
FROM useractivity
GROUP BY `date`
```

**Got output:**

```
Date         availableTime(Hours)

2016-02-28       9
2016-03-02       9
```

Here's the [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1200)

**Note:** 
Please ignore the `user_id` for the time being. I can solve it in application level but I want to deal with it in `MySQL`.

**The time interval can start one day and end more than one day later**

In a word, ***the available time is just the projection in the day axis (from start time and end time)***. If the start time doesn't project into the same day as end time then the start time would be considered the start_time of that particular day where the end time projects into.

**Pictorial View:**

[image]

So available time will be calculated from this screenshot as follows:

```
28 Feb = (t2-t1) + (t4- t3)

29 Feb = (t5 - t4)

02 Mar = (t7 - t6)
```

Comment: You get brownie points for adding a Fiddle, but it doesn't make your question any clearer.

Comment: Could the time interval start one day and end more than one day later? (ie start the 16:th, end the 22:nd?

Comment: Yes this scenario is possible. @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Updated Note section @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added the screenshot for better understanding the question. Please have a look at this.

Comment: i have added a answer please check

Comment: i have some change in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a query help of `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT sub_query.`date`, SUM(sub_query.available_time) FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time))= 0, 
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time),0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time)) > 0, 
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time, date_add(date(start_time),interval 24 hour)),0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(end_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time)) > 0,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,date(end_time), end_time) , 0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity 
) AS sub_query
GROUP BY sub_query.`date`

UNION

SELECT SELECTed_date `date`, 24 FROM 
(SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) SELECTed_date FROM
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE SELECTed_date between (SELECT min(date(start_time)) FROM useractivity) and (SELECT max(date(end_time)) FROM useractivity) 
AND SELECTed_date NOT IN(
SELECT miss_date FROM (
    SELECT date(start_time) AS miss_date FROM useractivity
    UNION 
    SELECT date(end_time) AS miss_date FROM useractivity
) AS miss
) ORDER BY `date`;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7fe7/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wanted a solution which meets the requirements. Please see the screenshot I've attached in my post. @VipinJain

Comment: Please run the query with another insert statement `INSERT INTO `useractivity` VALUES ('4', '1', '2016-03-02 22:00:00', '2016-03-06 19:00:00');`

Comment: according to my quey the output for 2016-03-02 is 83. what should be expected result for ?

Comment: Yes that's totally fine. But these 83 hours are spread across several dates (`2016-03-02`,`2016-03-03`,`2016-03-04`,`2016-03-05`)

Comment: Yes brother! Please let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: i have solution but i have no time to spend here. i am busy right now

Comment: Gradually you are approaching to the right answer brother. Please look at the **expected output** of my `post`. Is it possible to show such output?

Comment: I have changed answer if there is some date extra you can remove from use your own logic

Comment: Thanks @VipinJain. I've added an answer modifying your query a little to fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a date table to cross join to get the real start and end time in the day you want to split from the log time.

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
  `date` date ,
  `start_time` timestamp ,
  `end_time` timestamp 
);

INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160228','2016-02-28 00:00:00', '2016-02-29 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160229','2016-02-29 00:00:00', '2016-03-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160301','2016-03-01 00:00:00', '2016-03-02 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160302','2016-03-02 00:00:00', '2016-03-03 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160303','2016-03-03 00:00:00', '2016-03-04 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160304','2016-03-04 00:00:00', '2016-03-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160305','2016-03-05 00:00:00', '2016-03-06 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `dates` VALUES('20160306','2016-03-06 00:00:00', '2016-03-07 00:00:00');

SELECT 
    u.*,
    d.date,
    case when u.start_time<= d.start_time then d.start_time
      else u.start_time end as `start_time_in_the_day`,
    case when u.end_time> d.end_time then d.end_time
      else u.end_time end as `end_time_in_the_day`
FROM useractivity u
INNER JOIN dates d
ON u.start_time< d.end_time
   and u.end_time>= d.start_time
```

Then you just need to sum the hours between `end_time_in_the_day` and `start_time_in_the_day`.

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    date,
    sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time_in_the_day,end_time_in_the_day)) as `availableTime`
FROM(
    SELECT 
        u.*,
        d.date,
        case when u.start_time<= d.start_time then d.start_time
          else u.start_time end as `start_time_in_the_day`,
        case when u.end_time> d.end_time then d.end_time
          else u.end_time end as `end_time_in_the_day`
    FROM useractivity u
    INNER JOIN dates d
    ON u.start_time< d.end_time
       and u.end_time>= d.start_time) as t
group by user_id,date
```

My [SqlFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93d73/3)

And I think use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND...` instead `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR...` would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's another way but I think Vipin's answer is more scalable. +1

Comment: In fact I will calculate the available time in `MILLISECOND` unit. For readability I've added `HOUR` unit.

Comment: @AnonymousOne Vipin's answer also work. But I think using the data model to tell the story is much better than using complex algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified @Vipin Jain's query to fulfill the requirement:

```
SELECT sub_query.`date`, SUM(sub_query.available_time) FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time))= 0, 
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time),0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(start_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time)) > 0, 
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time, date_add(date(start_time),interval 24 hour)),0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(end_time,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date(start_time),date(end_time)) > 0,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,date(end_time), end_time) , 0) AS available_time
    FROM useractivity 
) AS sub_query
GROUP BY sub_query.`date`

UNION

SELECT SELECTed_date `date`, 24 FROM 
(SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) SELECTed_date FROM
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE SELECTed_date between (SELECT min(date(start_time)) FROM useractivity) and (SELECT max(date(end_time)) FROM useractivity) 
AND SELECTed_date NOT IN(
SELECT miss_date FROM (
    SELECT date(start_time) AS miss_date FROM useractivity
    UNION 
    SELECT date(end_time) AS miss_date FROM useractivity
) AS miss
) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM useractivity WHERE SELECTed_date BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)

ORDER BY `date`;
```